# "Refill" an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site with different message-boxes. The heads of these boxes should always have a different random color. In order to prevent messages next to each other having the same color, I use `splice` to remove the used colors from the array `colors`. At some point the array `colors` will be empty, which is why the remaining boxes will have no color. How can I "refill" the array, so every element gets a random color?

Here is my page: http://www.tdvk.de/.
Yellow is the default head color.

```
function selectColor() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    return colors.splice( random, 1 )[0];
}

var colors = [ "rgb(199, 179, 78)", "rgb(127, 195, 133)", "rgb(102, 169, 162)", "rgb(132, 122, 224)" ];

var i = 0;

while ( i != colors.length ) {
    $( "tr" ).each(function(i) {
        var head = $( ".msgHead", this );
        head.css( "background-color", selectColor() );
        i++;
    });
}

if { i = colors.length ) {
    /* reset array and continue */
}
```

Comment: Do you wish to refill the array with the exact same colors as before? Or entirely new random colors?  (And if the latter, can they overlap with colors you've used before?)

Comment: Why not just use the first element in the array, then move it to the end of the array, repeating as you use the first element, so you cycle through them?

Comment: @j08691 +1, just what I was working up to.

Comment: If you want the same colours, I would use another array and refill it like that. But if you do want the same colours, why not just cycle through the array then?

Comment: @Simon Mathewson If you wanted the elements next to each other to have different colors wouldn't you still have a chance to have back to back colors with the very last color in the array and then the first color in the array reset?

Answer (score 3):

How to refill with the same colors:

```
if ( i = colors.length ) {
    colors = [ "rgb(199, 179, 78)", "rgb(127, 195, 133)", "rgb(102, 169, 162)", "rgb(132, 122, 224)" ];
}
```

But like others have suggested, there are other ways to do this like wrapping around to the first element again and not splicing, or randomizing which values there are.

Comment: While pretty much doing exactly what the OP asked for, I think it would be better to create a copy of the original array and then copy it back rather than have two literal copies of the array in two separate places in your code that you have to remember to keep in sync.

Comment: I agree.  I was just trying to answer exactly what the OP asked.  Perhaps others can improve this answer with the various improvements mentioned.  What do you think OP?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `splice`, why not just iterate through them?

```
var selectedColorIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * colors.length);
function selectColor() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    return colors[selectedColorIndex];
}
```

Edit: this will now select a random element.

Comment: this way it's always the same order and not random

Comment: Yeah, if you are wanting to use the same colors over and over again, it does not make sense to alter the array.

Comment: This should pick a random element each time now.

Comment: Yep. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Now the console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: And shouldn't it be Math.floor instead of Math.round?

Comment: Yeah, right again. Lol. To make it fully uniform, you should use Math .floor

Answer (score 1):

Your question is leaving out some important details, but I think what you want to do is keep selecting random colors from the array, repeating no values until you've used every color and *only* then start repeating.

Probably you best solution might be to start with a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) of your original array and then just select each color in turn until you reach the last color. Then simply reshuffle and start back from the beginning.

So in pseudo-code, you'd have something like this:

```
shuffleArray
colorIndex = 0; 

while still selecting colors
    select color at array[colorIndex]
    colorIndex++
    if (colorIndex > array.length)
        colorIndex = 0;
        shuffleArray
```

For example:

```js
  // from http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

  function shuffle(array) {
    var m = array.length,
      t, i;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle…
    while (m) {

      // Pick a remaining element…
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

      // And swap it with the current element.
      t = array[m];
      array[m] = array[i];
      array[i] = t;
    }

    return array;
  }

var colorIndex = 0;
var colors = ["rgb(199, 179, 78)", "rgb(127, 195, 133)", "rgb(102, 169, 162)", "rgb(132, 122, 224)"];

var i = 0;

shuffle(colors);
while (i < 8) { 
  alert(colors[colorIndex++]);
  i++;
  if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
    shuffle(colors);
    colorIndex = 0;
  }
}
```

Note there is one more thing to consider. Regardless of how you do this, there is a possibility that the first element selected from your "refilled" array will be the same as the last element from the previous cycle. You might want to think about how to handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding color combinations, you can generate them on the fly

```
    var usedColors = []

    function randomDigit( max ){
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * max )
    }

    function getNewColor(){
        var max = 255
        var r = randomDigit( max )
        var g = randomDigit( max )
        var b = randomDigit( max )
        if ( !colorUsed( r, g, b ) ) return storeColor( r, g, b )
        else return getNewColor()
    }

    function storeColor( r, g, b ){
        usedColors[ r + "," + g + "," + b ] = true
        return [ r, g, b ]
    }

    function colorUsed(r,g,b){
        return usedColors[ r + "," + g + "," + b ]
    }

    var newColor = getNewColor()
```

Or if you prefer to have them predefined

```
    function shuffle(o){
        for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
    };

    var colors = [ "rgb(199, 179, 78)", "rgb(127, 195, 133)", "rgb(102, 169, 162)", "rgb(132, 122, 224)" ]

    function getColors(boxCount){
        var colorArr = []

        var fullIterations = Math.floor( boxCount / colors.length )

        var lastIteration = boxCount - fullIterations * colors.length

        for(var x = 0; x < fullIterations; x++){
            for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){ var color = colors[ i ]; colorArr.push(color);  }
            colors = shuffle( colors )
        }

        for(var x = 0; x < lastIteration; x++){ var color = colors[ x ]; colorArr.push(color);  }

        colors = shuffle( colors )

        return colorArr
    }

    var newColors = getColors(20)
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants. And besides, you could get some visually truly awful combinations of colors if you make it completely random. You might get all shades of gray for example.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're boxes are ordered from top to bottom. Why not select the random color by making sure the color of the previous box (above) is different than the current box. For example:

```
// remove splice from selectColor, the only thing selectColor needs to do now is select a random color from your list.

var previousColor = null;
$("tr").each(function (element) {
    // select random color
    var color = selectColor();
    // make sure it is different than previous color
    while (color === previousColor) selectColor();

    // ...
    // set element color
    // ...

    // make sure next element is different
    previousColor = color;
});
```

Comment: Algorithms that are not guaranteed to exit (like this one) make me sad. A better solution would be to remove the last color and then readd it after the next color is selected. That way you never get caught that while loop.

Comment: @MattBurland I know, this particular sort of random algorithm bothers me as well, but just doing some probability will make you feel better. (e.g., 75% chance `selectColor` is called only once, 93.75% chance it is called only twice, 98.4% chance it is called only three times. etc.)

Comment: @MattBurland In fact, I suspect the average case running time of the non-exiting algorithm is better than removing and re-adding an element to an array.